# QLE2562 HBA/qla2xxx problems on CentOS 5.3

Tags: linux, centos

I have several Linux servers (SunFire X4270) running CentOS 5.3 (kernel-2.6.18-128.1.16.el5) with Qlogic FC-8 QLE2562 HBA... I'm experiencing a lot of problem with these new servers, one of them displaying every second the following messages:

```
qla2xxx 0000:2f:00.0: Passthru CT request failed to login management server
qla2xxx 0000:2f:00.0: Passthru CT failed
qla2xxx 0000:2f:00.1: Passthru CT request failed to login management server
qla2xxx 0000:2f:00.1: Passthru CT failed
```

Also, I have several servers ending in panic with the following trace (see below).
I have tried several kernel versions of CentOS 5.3 2.6.18-128.el5 and 2.6.18-128.1.16.el5 (latest), also I have tried the latest driver from Qlogic with 4.06 embedded QLE2562 firmware, without success. Strange thing is that I have one other server, with the same hardware/software configuration running well (stable...). Sun support (available with these servers) has not been able to solve the problem yet...
Any ideas ?

```
qla2xxx_eh_abort(8): aborting sp ffff81037d86ebc0 from RISC. pid=952 sp->state=7 q->q_flag=2
qla2xxx 0000:2f:00.1: Mailbox command timeout occurred. Issuing ISP abort.
NMI Watchdog detected LOCKUP on CPU 13
CPU 13
Modules linked in: autofs4 sunrpc ipv6 xfrm_nalgo crypto_api cpufreq_ondemand acpi_cpufreq freq_table dm_mirror dm_multipath scsi_dh video hwmon backlight sbs i2c_ec button battery asus_acpi acpi_memhotplug ac parport_pc lp parport joydev qla2xxx(U) qla2xxx_conf(U) igb i2c_i801 intermodule(U) i2c_core sg pcspkr dm_raid45 dm_message dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod dm_mem_cache ahci libata shpchp mptsas mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_sas sd_mod scsi_mod ext3 jbd uhci_hcd ohci_hcd ehci_hcd
Pid: 2982, comm: scsi_eh_8 Tainted: G      2.6.18-128.el5 #1
RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8000c6f2>]  [<ffffffff8000c6f2>] __delay+0x8/0x10
RSP: 0018:ffff81067dc7db88  EFLAGS: 00000097
RAX: 00000000ecd06b41 RBX: 000000000018c42b RCX: 00000000ecd05808
RDX: 0000000000000324 RSI: 0000000000000046 RDI: 0000000000003689
RBP: ffffc20000034000 R08: 0000000000000002 R09: ffff81067dc7db54
R10: 0000000000000001 R11: ffffffff80213fbd R12: ffff81037e84c4f8
R13: 0000000000000246 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000000000
FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff81067fc46140(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0018 ES: 0018 CR0: 000000008005003b
CR2: 00000000006bb424 CR3: 000000067d035000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
Process scsi_eh_8 (pid: 2982, threadinfo ffff81067dc7c000, task ffff81010c6ec040)
Stack:  ffffffff8827f743 ffff81037e84c4f8 ffff81067dc7dc90 ffff81060000dc20
 ffff81037fa461c8 ffff81037e84c4f8 ffff81067dc7dc90 0000000000000100
 ffffffff88285488 ffff81037fa461c8 ffff81037e84c4f8 ffff81067dc7dc90
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff8827f743>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_reset_chip+0x157/0x47e
 [<ffffffff88285488>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_abort_isp+0x6c/0x70b
 [<ffffffff88286dfd>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_mailbox_command+0x48e/0x553
 [<ffffffff88286960>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_mbx_sem_timeout+0x0/0xf
 [<ffffffff882886f5>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_issue_iocb_timeout+0x5f/0xc0
 [<ffffffff88288fd0>] :qla2xxx:qla24xx_abort_command+0xf9/0x1a5
 [<ffffffff88289099>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_abort_command+0x1d/0x124
 [<ffffffff80064c08>] _spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x8/0x9
 [<ffffffff8827f1e6>] :qla2xxx:qla2xxx_eh_abort+0x9f8/0xba0
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff8807919f>] :scsi_mod:scsi_error_handler+0x290/0x4ac
 [<ffffffff88078f0f>] :scsi_mod:scsi_error_handler+0x0/0x4ac
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff80032360>] kthread+0xfe/0x132
 [<ffffffff8005dfb1>] child_rip+0xa/0x11
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff80032262>] kthread+0x0/0x132
 [<ffffffff8005dfa7>] child_rip+0x0/0x11


Code: 29 c8 48 39 f8 72 f5 c3 41 54 83 3d ad d8 3c 00 00 49 89 f4
Kernel panic - not syncing: nmi watchdog
 BUG: warning at kernel/panic.c:137/panic() (Tainted: G     )

Call Trace:
 <NMI>  [<ffffffff8008efff>] panic+0x1da/0x1eb
 [<ffffffff8006ba21>] _show_stack+0xdb/0xea
 [<ffffffff8006bb14>] show_registers+0xe4/0x100
 [<ffffffff8006537d>] die_nmi+0x66/0xa3
 [<ffffffff80065ac3>] nmi_watchdog_tick+0x157/0x1d3
 [<ffffffff800656e1>] default_do_nmi+0x81/0x225
 [<ffffffff8006594e>] do_nmi+0x43/0x61
 [<ffffffff80064fa7>] nmi+0x7f/0x88
 [<ffffffff80213fbd>] pci_mmcfg_read+0x0/0x92
 [<ffffffff8000c6f2>] __delay+0x8/0x10
 <<EOE>>  [<ffffffff8827f743>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_reset_chip+0x157/0x47e
 [<ffffffff88285488>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_abort_isp+0x6c/0x70b
 [<ffffffff88286dfd>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_mailbox_command+0x48e/0x553
 [<ffffffff88286960>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_mbx_sem_timeout+0x0/0xf
 [<ffffffff882886f5>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_issue_iocb_timeout+0x5f/0xc0
 [<ffffffff88288fd0>] :qla2xxx:qla24xx_abort_command+0xf9/0x1a5
 [<ffffffff88289099>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_abort_command+0x1d/0x124
 [<ffffffff80064c08>] _spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x8/0x9
 [<ffffffff8827f1e6>] :qla2xxx:qla2xxx_eh_abort+0x9f8/0xba0
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff8807919f>] :scsi_mod:scsi_error_handler+0x290/0x4ac
 [<ffffffff88078f0f>] :scsi_mod:scsi_error_handler+0x0/0x4ac
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff80032360>] kthread+0xfe/0x132
 [<ffffffff8005dfb1>] child_rip+0xa/0x11
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff80032262>] kthread+0x0/0x132
 [<ffffffff8005dfa7>] child_rip+0x0/0x11

BUG: warning at drivers/input/serio/i8042.c:846/i8042_panic_blink() (Tainted: G     )

Call Trace:
 <NMI>  [<ffffffff801fa015>] i8042_panic_blink+0x112/0x2a5
 [<ffffffff8008efa5>] panic+0x180/0x1eb
 [<ffffffff8006ba21>] _show_stack+0xdb/0xea
 [<ffffffff8006bb14>] show_registers+0xe4/0x100
 [<ffffffff8006537d>] die_nmi+0x66/0xa3
 [<ffffffff80065ac3>] nmi_watchdog_tick+0x157/0x1d3
 [<ffffffff800656e1>] default_do_nmi+0x81/0x225
 [<ffffffff8006594e>] do_nmi+0x43/0x61
 [<ffffffff80064fa7>] nmi+0x7f/0x88
 [<ffffffff80213fbd>] pci_mmcfg_read+0x0/0x92
 [<ffffffff8000c6f2>] __delay+0x8/0x10
 <<EOE>>  [<ffffffff8827f743>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_reset_chip+0x157/0x47e
 [<ffffffff88285488>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_abort_isp+0x6c/0x70b
 [<ffffffff88286dfd>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_mailbox_command+0x48e/0x553
 [<ffffffff88286960>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_mbx_sem_timeout+0x0/0xf
 [<ffffffff882886f5>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_issue_iocb_timeout+0x5f/0xc0
 [<ffffffff88288fd0>] :qla2xxx:qla24xx_abort_command+0xf9/0x1a5
 [<ffffffff88289099>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_abort_command+0x1d/0x124
 [<ffffffff80064c08>] _spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x8/0x9
 [<ffffffff8827f1e6>] :qla2xxx:qla2xxx_eh_abort+0x9f8/0xba0
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff8807919f>] :scsi_mod:scsi_error_handler+0x290/0x4ac
 [<ffffffff88078f0f>] :scsi_mod:scsi_error_handler+0x0/0x4ac
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff80032360>] kthread+0xfe/0x132
 [<ffffffff8005dfb1>] child_rip+0xa/0x11
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff80032262>] kthread+0x0/0x132
 [<ffffffff8005dfa7>] child_rip+0x0/0x11

BUG: warning at drivers/input/serio/i8042.c:849/i8042_panic_blink() (Tainted: G     )

Call Trace:
 <NMI>  [<ffffffff801fa0fe>] i8042_panic_blink+0x1fb/0x2a5
 [<ffffffff8008efa5>] panic+0x180/0x1eb
 [<ffffffff8006ba21>] _show_stack+0xdb/0xea
 [<ffffffff8006bb14>] show_registers+0xe4/0x100
 [<ffffffff8006537d>] die_nmi+0x66/0xa3
 [<ffffffff80065ac3>] nmi_watchdog_tick+0x157/0x1d3
 [<ffffffff800656e1>] default_do_nmi+0x81/0x225
 [<ffffffff8006594e>] do_nmi+0x43/0x61
 [<ffffffff80064fa7>] nmi+0x7f/0x88
 [<ffffffff80213fbd>] pci_mmcfg_read+0x0/0x92
 [<ffffffff8000c6f2>] __delay+0x8/0x10
 <<EOE>>  [<ffffffff8827f743>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_reset_chip+0x157/0x47e
 [<ffffffff88285488>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_abort_isp+0x6c/0x70b
 [<ffffffff88286dfd>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_mailbox_command+0x48e/0x553
 [<ffffffff88286960>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_mbx_sem_timeout+0x0/0xf
 [<ffffffff882886f5>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_issue_iocb_timeout+0x5f/0xc0
 [<ffffffff88288fd0>] :qla2xxx:qla24xx_abort_command+0xf9/0x1a5
 [<ffffffff88289099>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_abort_command+0x1d/0x124
 [<ffffffff80064c08>] _spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x8/0x9
 [<ffffffff8827f1e6>] :qla2xxx:qla2xxx_eh_abort+0x9f8/0xba0
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff8807919f>] :scsi_mod:scsi_error_handler+0x290/0x4ac
 [<ffffffff88078f0f>] :scsi_mod:scsi_error_handler+0x0/0x4ac
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff80032360>] kthread+0xfe/0x132
 [<ffffffff8005dfb1>] child_rip+0xa/0x11
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff80032262>] kthread+0x0/0x132
 [<ffffffff8005dfa7>] child_rip+0x0/0x11

BUG: warning at drivers/input/serio/i8042.c:851/i8042_panic_blink() (Tainted: G     )

Call Trace:
 <NMI>  [<ffffffff801fa17b>] i8042_panic_blink+0x278/0x2a5
 [<ffffffff8008efa5>] panic+0x180/0x1eb
 [<ffffffff8006ba21>] _show_stack+0xdb/0xea
 [<ffffffff8006bb14>] show_registers+0xe4/0x100
 [<ffffffff8006537d>] die_nmi+0x66/0xa3
 [<ffffffff80065ac3>] nmi_watchdog_tick+0x157/0x1d3
 [<ffffffff800656e1>] default_do_nmi+0x81/0x225
 [<ffffffff8006594e>] do_nmi+0x43/0x61
 [<ffffffff80064fa7>] nmi+0x7f/0x88
 [<ffffffff80213fbd>] pci_mmcfg_read+0x0/0x92
 [<ffffffff8000c6f2>] __delay+0x8/0x10
 <<EOE>>  [<ffffffff8827f743>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_reset_chip+0x157/0x47e
 [<ffffffff88285488>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_abort_isp+0x6c/0x70b
 [<ffffffff88286dfd>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_mailbox_command+0x48e/0x553
 [<ffffffff88286960>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_mbx_sem_timeout+0x0/0xf
 [<ffffffff882886f5>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_issue_iocb_timeout+0x5f/0xc0
 [<ffffffff88288fd0>] :qla2xxx:qla24xx_abort_command+0xf9/0x1a5
 [<ffffffff88289099>] :qla2xxx:qla2x00_abort_command+0x1d/0x124
 [<ffffffff80064c08>] _spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x8/0x9
 [<ffffffff8827f1e6>] :qla2xxx:qla2xxx_eh_abort+0x9f8/0xba0
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff8807919f>] :scsi_mod:scsi_error_handler+0x290/0x4ac
 [<ffffffff88078f0f>] :scsi_mod:scsi_error_handler+0x0/0x4ac
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff80032360>] kthread+0xfe/0x132
 [<ffffffff8005dfb1>] child_rip+0xa/0x11
 [<ffffffff8009d909>] keventd_create_kthread+0x0/0xc4
 [<ffffffff80032262>] kthread+0x0/0x132
 [<ffffffff8005dfa7>] child_rip+0x0/0x11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you radius. It seems that the `Passthru CT request failed` is an hardware problem (not fully validated yet). For the other big issue, it is related with the PCIe Active Riser cards we have (Sun X4270 hardware): those cards contain a PCIe switch conflicting with the QLE2562 (issue validated/reproduced by Sun support level 2)... If you encounter this problem with Sun hardware, try to put the HBA in PCIe slots which are not switched (slot 0 and 3 on an X4270, because Riser 0 is not an active Riser, it's on a 16x slot). Sun is working to fix the problem on their machines to allow the user to put the HBA in any slots.

Answer (score 1):

For `qla2xxx 0000:2f:00.0: Passthru CT request failed to login management server` if it appends only on one server you may have an hardware problem with the card. Did you try to put this card in another server ?
For the server running well, I would try the same test by putting his card from serverA to serverB and see if serverB start to be stable or if serverA is still stable.

Answer (score 1):

qla2xxx_eh_abort(8):aborting sp.
This issue is totally related to HBA card which is installed on sun blade servers.Actually we have faced this issue recently dated 16-Dec-2012. So kindly replace the hba card and it will resolve the issue totally.